# Can 'file.read() function' not be used twice?

Tags: python

Can 'file.read() function' not be used twice?

I executed file.read() at first and it worked well but when I tried to use the function before I close the file it didn't work.

```py
f=open("text.txt","r")
f.read()
'hello\nbye'
f.read()
''
```

Comment: The first time you read it the file pointer has moved to the end of the file. The second time, there's nothing left to read.

Comment: Reading a file is like using a bookmark, each time you read something you start from the bookmark and move the bookmark accordingly. If you want to read something again you'll have to : move the bookmark back or reopen the file in someway.

Answer (score 2):

> If the end of the file has been reached, `f.read()` will return an empty string (`''`).

More information can be found here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects

Answer (score 1):

Save to an object

```py
with open( "text.txt","r" ) as f :
    file = f.readlines()
```

and you have the content stored in "file" object

Answer (score 1):

When you read for the first time, the cursor reaches the end of file. Move cursor back to start of file with `seek(0)`:

```
In [28]: f=open("test.txt","r")

In [29]: f.read()
Out[29]: 'hello\nbye'

In [30]: f.read()
Out[30]: ''

In [31]: f.seek(0)
Out[31]: 0

In [32]: f.read()
Out[32]: 'hello\nbye'
```